# What is Kafka Partition Rebalancing expected time?

Tags: apache-kafka

How long does Partition Rebalancing take when a new Consumer joins the group?
What factors can affect this?

In my understanding, these factors play role:

1. Consumers needs to finish processing the data they polled last time.
2. Coordinator waits for Consumer to send JoinGroup request - for how long?
3. Consumers send SyncGroup request (is there a delay between receiving JoinGroup response and sending SyncGroup request?)

In a normal situation, assuming that Consumers process data instantly, how long should one expect to Partition Rebalancing to take place?

Answer (score 0):

2. Coordinator waits for at most rebalance.timeout.ms (1 minute by default). If Consumer does not join during this time it is considered dead. But if all consumers re-join before this, the Coordinator will not wait further (my assumption).
3. Usual Consumers send Sync group as soon as they received the JoinGroup response. Leader needs more time (to perform partition assignment logic).

Source:
https://www.confluent.io/online-talks/everything-you-always-wanted-to-know-about-kafkas-rebalance-protocol-but-were-afraid-to-ask-on-demand/